# client tcp socket port changes after connection to server

Tags: boost, binding, boost-asio

Using boost asio I am trying to bind socket to specific port and the bind is correct until I connect to server.

```
socket.open(tcp::v4(), ec);
socket.set_option(tcp::socket::reuse_address(true),ec);
socket.bind(tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port_client), ec);
.
.
cout <<"before connect:"<<socket.local_endpoint().address().to_string()<<":"<<socket.local_endpoint().port()<<endl;
```

The port is ok till this point but when I connect it to server:

```
boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator,ec);
.
cout <<"after connect:"<<socket.local_endpoint().address().to_string()<<":"<<socket.local_endpoint().port()<<endl;
```

The local port changes to any other port. Can somebody please help?
Also the the address comes out to be 0.0.0.0 why?

Answer (score 1):

Waited too long for the answer... Solved the issue myself. The problem was with the connect command.

I was using the connect command for basic_socket but the connect command should be:

```
socket.connect(*endpoint_iterator,ec);
```

Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can print tcp::v4(),this value is "0.0.0.0" if not point addres